# Resize images in markdown files for websites built usign Docusuarus

Tags: html, docusaurus

I am trying to build a documentation website for a project. The images I am using are large in size and I'd like to resize them using the HTML tag style="zoom:33%;". However, on running the build command it throws errors.
I have tried to replace the markdown tags with the HTML tag but it doesn't work either.

`<img src="externel-link.png" alt="img" style="zoom:33%;" />`

Some help, please.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work because there is no zoom in css...

You could use `transform: scale(1.33);`

So something like this will probably work:

 `<img src="externel-link.png" alt="img" style="transform: scale(1.33);" />`

Comment: Throws the following error

Docusaurus Node/SSR could not render static page with path "/docs/books" because of following error:

Error: Minified React error #62; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=62 for the full message or use the non-minified 
dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at a.b.renderDOM (main:91494:354)
    at a.b.render (main:91489:399)
    at a.b.read (main:91488:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (main:91499:138)
    at doRender (main:13714:356)
    at async serverEntry_render (main:13713:294)

Answer (score 1):

Using an img tag with a style prop works in docusaurus 2.x:

```
<img src={require("./photo.png").default} style={{transform:'scale(1.33)'}} />
```

If it is an external link:

```
<img src="externalink.jpg" style={{transform:'scale(1.33)'}} />
```